# SQL Server 2008 Analysis services instance - can connect locally but not remote

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas

I can connect locally to a SQL Server 2008 SSAS instance, but not remotely via SSMS on my workstation. I have admin rights so something else must be missing.

I seem to have run into this before but don't recall what I did to resolve it. No issues connecting to the database or SSRS instances on this machine, just SSAS. Both my workstation and the server instance are on the same domain.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe there is a firewall preventing the access to the server from your workstation? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174937.aspx

Comment: Yep, just checked.  Some of those ports like 2383 are not open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a firewall preventing the access to the server from your workstation? See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174937.aspx